# Error on line 2 at column 1: Document is empty on php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got this:

> "error This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 2 at column 1: Document is empty Below is a rendering of
>   the page up to the first error."

When I run in google chrome this code:

```
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully\n";

$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$root_element = "catalog";
$xml   .="\n"."<".$root_element.">"."\n"; 
$sql="select * from `book`;";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
$row_cnt=$result->num_rows;
if (!$result){
    die('Invalid query:'.mysql_error());
}
 if ($row_cnt>0){
    while($result_array =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {    $xml .="\t<".$database.""; //<book

        foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
        {

            $xml .="\t\t<$key>"; //<id>
            $xml .="$value";      //value
            $xml .="</$key>\n";    //</id>


        }
        $xml .="\t</".$database.">\n";
    }
}
$xml .="\n</$root_element>";
header("Content-Type:text/xml");
echo $xml;

?>
```

and how I can show it like this?

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
```

Comment: What do you get if you run this code directly? You're outputting an error message if you fail to connect, and a success message if you do connect - either way, you're producing invalid XML.

Comment: You also never close the `book` element and aren't making the `id` attribute. e.g. `$xml .="\t<".$database.">";`

Comment: when i run the code i have successfully connection and show me the error message - if i press view source i can see the results

Comment: then take those results and run them through an xml validator.

Answer (score 1):

Typos:

```
{    $xml .="\t<".$database.""; //<book
                             ^--- forgot a > here
```

So you're generating

```
<foo
  <bar></bar>
```

which is illegal/invalid XML, hence your error.

Comment: this solution doesn't match the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line

```
echo "Connected successfully\n";
```

as it will make your XML invalid